# For loop dentro de outro For loop

Tags: r

estou com um problema em iterar um conjunto de dados.

A ideia principal era separar o conjunto de dados principal em outros, um referente à cada time, a partir de um for loop. Depois, aplicar outro for loop para percorrer as linhas de cada conjunto e criar uma coluna com os gols que o time fez. Fiz a seguinte tentativa, que deu errado:

```
library(readr)
  library(magrittr)
  library(dplyr)
  library(lubridate)
  library(zoo)


   fut_uk <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jokecamp/FootballData/master/football-data.co.uk/england/2020-2021%20(Until%20Jan%2022)/Premier.csv") %>% 
                  select(Data = Date, HomeTeam, AwayTeam, FTR, FTHG, FTAG, FTR, HTHG, HTAG, HTR, HS, AS, HST, AST, HC, AC) %>% 
                  mutate(Data = as.Date(Data, format = "%d/%m/%y"))


   for (time in unique(fut_uk$HomeTeam)) {
  
     assign(time, fut_uk %>% 
                    filter(HomeTeam == time | AwayTeam == time) %>% 
                    mutate(Gols = FTHG * NA))
     
       for (i in seq_along(time[,2])) {
         
             if (time[i,2] == time) {
               time[i,16] <- time[i, 5]
             } else {
               time[i,16] <- time[i, 6]
               
             }
       
        } 
    
   }
```

Que retorna o seguinte erro:

```
Error in time[, 2] : número incorreto de dimensões
```

Alguém sabe como resolver isso? Muito obrigado!

Comment: O teste lógico do `for` é perpassar a variável `time` no vetor estabelecido. Em cada laço o a variável é reestabelecida, sendo um item de 1 dimensão. Então, não tem como usar seq_along e nem localizar uma segunda dimensão como time[,2]. Este é o erro.

Comment: Para complementar o comentário do @DanielIkenaga, o `for` avalia a variável iteradora só uma vez no início de cada iteração, não pode alterar o valor dentro do ciclo. E é até bastante confuso escolher o mesmo nome para o resultado do pipe no `assign`. Escolha outro nome e o ciclo deve correr.

Comment: Além disso, `FTHG * NA` dá sempre `NA`. Porquê multiplicar? `Gols = NA_real_` é mais fácil e dá o mesmo resultado.

Comment: Não percebo o que pretende com *"criar uma coluna com os gols que o time fez"*. Essa coluna já existe na base, é a coluna `FTHG`. E para separa por time basta fazer `time_list <- split(fut_uk, fut_uk$HomeTeam)`.